# Use specific cols in pandas and change names also

Tags: pandas

I want to read a set of columns from a csv file and change their names also. Tried using this code:
`data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding='latin-1', ​usecols=['name', 'text', 'gender'], names=['gender', 'username', 'tweet'])`

And it gives me this result:
`ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['text', 'name']`

Is there a quick way to do it inside the read_csv function or should I change the names of the columns using the ordinary way after reading the file?
Thanks.

Comment: the error is caused because the columns 'text' and 'name' are not found. Maybe your csv contains space in headers.

Comment: @Bricam They are found when I remove the second parameter: `names=['gender', 'username', 'tweet']`, it works fine, but without assigning the new names.

Comment: try to passing the argument header=0